# Consecutio temporum et praesens historicum

Tags: syntax, conjunctive, subordinate-clause, praesens-historicum, consecutio-temporum

Sometimes in an intensive narrative the present tense is used to refer to past events.
Such use of the present tense is called *praesens historicum*.
It is formally present but semantically past.
How does *consecutio temporum* of conjunctive subordinate clauses work with it?
Should I use present and perfect conjunctive (as if *praesens historicum* was present) or imperfect and pluperfect conjunctive (as if *praesens historicum* was a past tense)?
If both are possible, is there a difference?

Answer (score 6):

In English, your *consecutio temporum* is usually called the ‘sequence of tenses’. There is a general rule that in the principal sentence (i) a primary tense  is followed in the subordinate clause by a primary tense, and (ii) a historic tense by a historic tense. In subordinate clauses the subjunctive is usual, incomplete action being represented by the present and imperfect, and completed action by the perfect and pluperfect. The historic present (*praesens historicum* ) and historic infinitive are mostly used with historic sequence.

There are exceptions, though — e.g. to avoid ambiguity, or in a consecutive clause if it describes a completed action; and in *oratio obliqua*, conditional statements have a different set of rules.

This is a tricky business in English, too — look at the difference between, for example, *I would have liked to see* and *I would like to have seen*, and you may reflect that a majority of speakers rely instead of either of these on *I would have liked to have seen*, without regard for the niceties of good grammar.

Answer (score 2):

Tuomo Pekkanen's *Ars Grammatica – Latinan kielioppi* (§116, lisäys 3) mentions that the historical present can be treated as either a present tense or as a past tense when *consecutio temporum* is concerned.
It gives this example without any citation or further explanation:

> *Quod cum videret, quaerit, quae causa sit/esset.*
>   When he saw it, he asked what the reason was.

I know this is not very convincing evidence, but it does support the idea of two possibilities.

Comment: I should guess that 'quaerit, quae causa sit' translates as 'he asked 'what might the reason be?' and 'quae causa esset' as 'what might the reason have been?'

Comment: @TomCotton, the grammar states that both mean the same thing: "he asked what the reason was". Therefore I would expect "he asked what the reason might have been" would have either *fuerit* or *fuisset*. I tend to agree with the grammar, but I don't have a strong opinion; I'm mainly reproducing its statement here.

Comment: There's no problem. Each of my translations, in effect, means the same thing, too. They are just a matter of style and personal preference, unless we are being very, very picky!

Comment: I seem to have seen past tenses used in this case, i.e. in my experience the praesens historicum normally counts as a past tense as regards the consecutio temporum. Wherever a full shift to an all-present account is possible, I'd expect *all* verbs in that part of the story to reflect this—no mixing. So in your example I would most definitely expect *esset* because of *videret*. But perhaps we should do some corporeal research first...